# Is is possible to tunnel a port over SSH for the current user only?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to establish an SSH tunnel, but I'm on a shared system. I'd rather not share access to the tunnel with the rest of the users. Is there any way to restrict the local port for my use only, as a standard user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't restrict TCP/UDP socket access by user like that; you want to use a unix socket for this, because they show up as a file in the filesystem and can have permissions applied to them. The problem here is that I don't think there are any SSH clients that support creating unix socket tunnels (and the OpenSSHd server does not either, so you'd need to run a customized SSH client on your shared system and SSH to back to where you want the other SSH tunnel endpoint to be). Furthermore, you'd have to make sure that the application(s) that you want to tunnel support unix sockets, which it might not.

If the application you want to tunnel does support filesystem pipes or unix sockets, then you might be in luck, but it'll still require a good bit of work. You can try creating a program which opens a unix socket and connects it to STDIN/STDOUT, and then use SSH in non-interactive mode to tunnel that data over the default PTY channels instead of a socket tunnel. Use the same program on the other end of the SSH connection to connect it to a local unix socket.

Voilà‎! A socket tunnel, secured over SSH, with additional permissions and ACLs on both ends. Creating the program (aka, the hard part) left as an exercise for the reader.